# GPU program failed to execute : cublas runtime error

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to train a network via pytorch on CUDA enabled GeForce GTX 1070 gpu. I don't understand the error nor have I found any similar problem anywhere. I don't know if its cuda's issue or something in my code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 497, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 167, in main
    train(train_loader, model, criterion, optimizer, epoch, normalizer)
  File "main.py", line 244, in train
    output = model(*input_var)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 357, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\1546544\Desktop\ML\model.py", line 147, in forward
    atom_fea = conv_func(atom_fea, nbr_fea, nbr_fea_idx)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 357, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\1546544\Desktop\ML\model.py", line 66, in forward
    total_gated_fea = self.fc_full(total_nbr_fea)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 357, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\linear.py", line 55, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 837, in linear
    output = input.matmul(weight.t())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\variable.py", line 386, in matmul
    return torch.matmul(self, other)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\functional.py", line 192, in matmul
    output = torch.mm(tensor1, tensor2)
RuntimeError: cublas runtime error : the GPU program failed to execute at C:/Anaconda2/conda-bld/pytorch_1519496000060/work/torch/lib/THC/THCBlas.cu:247
```

Comment: how did you install PyTorch?

Comment: Could you show some code?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem.

I **fixed** this problem by *dataset label* correction. 
I mean, *training label* was incorrect for my dataset. That's why it was failed during `backward()` pass.

So, checking the **expected label** after loading it from disk/database might be helpful.

Comment: nice job!!!  i fixed this error. when i classify 40 classes but i use linear(10) that encounter this problem